# How to plot valleys correctly in Matlab using Findpeaks

Tags: matlab, plot, max, minimum

I have a vector Ir and I am trying to identify peaks and valleys using the findpeaks function.

However, when I plot the valleys I get the following image, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

This is my code, I assume I am doing something wrong when I am invertig the dataset?

```
[ypk,yt] = findpeaks( Ir,'MinPeakProminence', 5);
ypk2=[]
yt2=[]
for w = 1:numel(ypk)
    if ypk(w) >=0
        ypk2 = [ypk2;ypk(w)]
        yt2 = [yt2;yt(w)]
    end
end


%upsidedownIr = max(Ir)-Ir
upsidedownIr = -Ir
[ypk3,yt3] = findpeaks( upsidedownIr,'MinPeakProminence', 2);
ypk4=[]
yt4=[]
for w = 1:numel(ypk3)
    if ypk3(w) >=0
        ypk4 = [ypk4;ypk3(w)]
        yt4 = [yt4;yt3(w)]
    end
end


figure(1), clf

plot(time,Ir,'k-')
hold on
plot(time(yt2),ypk2,'r*')
plot(time(yt4),ypk4,'g*')
```

Comment: Well what I can see is that the sign of the valleys is wrong it should be negative, try -1*ypk4 if my assumption is not wrong

Comment: Thanks, @Umar! Where exactly do you see that? I am asking because I am new to this and I am not sure where I should change the sign. Sorry, just saw your edit!

Comment: Perfect @Umar! Thanks, please post as answer and I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign of your valleys is incorrect , please negate it otherwise the values are correct

try `-1*ypk4` in the end , You are inverting your `Ir` in your code which gives you valleys as positive values so you have to again turn them to to negative to get the correct answer 
 or

```
ypk4 = -1*ypk4
```